# Additional component in <MuiThemeProvider /> results in blank page w/ no error messages

Tags: javascript, meteor, material-ui

I have recently installed Material UI into my Meteor application using `npm install --save material ui`

I have gotten the `<Header />` component showing up in my `app.js` file, but whenever I add other components, `localhost:3000` simply displays a blank page. Please see my code below:

**header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <AppBar
        title="Header"
        titleStyle={{textAlign: "center"}}
        showMenuIconButton={false}
      /> 
   );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import Header from './components/header'; 
import NewPost from './components/new_post';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <Header />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );  
};

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.render-target'));
});
```

**THE ABOVE CODE WORKS WELL (see screenshot below)**
[image: Working with one component (<Header />)]

**However, if I add another component I get a blank screen**

*header.js is the same*

**new_post.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

class NewPost extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
      hintText="Full width"
      fullWidth={true}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default NewPost;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import Header from './components/header'; 
import NewPost from './components/new_post';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <Header />
      <NewPost />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );  
};

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.render-target'));
});
```

**The result is simply a blank screen**

Why does adding one more component (`<NewPost />`)inside of `<MuiThemeProvider>` result in a blank screen? I referred to the `material-ui` documentation and their sample projects but their application structure is not similar to mine. Any advice? Please let me know if you need more info to make this question clearer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wow very strange but I managed to get it working by simply adding a `<div>`

**app.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <NewPost />
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );  
}
Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.render-target'));
});
```

[image: working app]

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain why adding a `div` makes this all work. Thank you!

Comment: It seems MuiThemeProvider will only play nice with a single child element. I noticed this in browser console...  

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `MuiThemeProvider`, expected a single ReactElement.
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
    in App

Answer (score 0):

> I would really appreciate if anyone could explain why adding a div
>   makes this all work

If you look at the browser warning, "*Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `MuiThemeProvider`, **expected a single ReactElement**.*".

So, when you add a `<div/>` around your components, it wraps them together and turns them into a single react element.

Answer (score 0):

MuiThemeProvider renders as null so you have to wrap children do anything - for example React.Fragment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.